# How to handle rewards for variable length episodes with reward at terminal state

Tags: reinforcement-learning

The objective of game is for rabbit to find the single cabbage in a very large field in min time and eat it. The action space is discrete (up/down/right/left), the state space is continuous (a very large field). Episode ends after 100 jumps, when rabbit finds the cabbage, or gets out of the field (whichever happens first). One of state variables is distance to the cabbage. Since the field is very large I am using reward shaping (small positive/negative reward for getting closer to/farther from the cabbage). In order to get to the cabbage in min time the reward should be 0 for each jump and 1 when cabbage is found. However, shaping the reward breaks the scheme. Is there an elegant way to employ reward shaping in this game and how? Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I apologize, The reward for min time should be -1 for each jump and 0 for finding the cabbage. How to combine it with reward shaping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found that potential-based shaping function might be a solution. In this case potential F of each state s is distance to cabbage. Original reward R is 0 for non terminal state, -1 if rabbit gets out of the field, 1-time/T if rabbit finds the cabbage where T is episode duration. Terminal states are finding the cabbage and getting out of the field. The new reward R'=R+(F(s')-F(s))/maxDist. I would appreciate any ideas.